# How does drupal choose which function to process a form submit?

Tags: php, drupal, form-submit, drupal-fapi

I'm really confused,can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

Check the entries for 'Validating Forms' and 'Submitting Forms' in the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826) - by default Drupal will look for a function that is named `[form_id]_submit`, but this is just the default behavior. You can override this (or add more than one submit callback) by putting the callback function names in the `#submit` attribute of the form declaration (see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#submit-prop).

Comment: notice it can run *more than one* function in #validate and #submit.